# Setting Default Value in .build method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to submit a nested form when you create a school, you can also create a admin with it. When I try to save the form with the default value of owner set to true and status set to active, it saves the form but doesnt save those values in the database

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_admin!, except: [:index, :new, :create]
    def show
        @school = School.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end
    def new
        @school = School.new
        @admin = @school.admins.build(:owner => true, :status => "active")
    end
    def create
        @school = School.new(school_params)
        if @school.save
            redirect_to new_admin_session_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end

    end
    def edit
        @school = School.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    end
    def update
        @school = School.find_by_slug(params[:id])

        if @school.update_attributes(school_params)
            redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @school
        else
         render :action => 'edit'
        end
    end
    def team
        @teams = Admin.all
    end
    private

    def school_params
        params.require(:school).permit(:school_name, :latitude, :longitude, :radius, admins_attributes: [ :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :image ])
    end
end
```

---

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :admins
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :admins

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :school_name, use: :slugged

    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
        school_name?
    end

    # Validation

    validates :school_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    validates :latitude, presence: true
    validates :longitude, presence: true
    validates :radius, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }

end
```

---

```
%nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top{role:"navigation"}
    %div.container
        %div.navbar-header
            %button.navbar-toggle.collapsed{"data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-target" => "#navbar", "aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-controls" => "navbar"}
                %span.sr-only Toggle Navigation
                %span.icon-bar
                %span.icon-bar
                %span.icon-bar
            %a.navbar-brand{"href" => "/", "id"=> "brand"} QuickAlert
        %div#navbar.collapse.navbar-collapse
            %ul.nav.navbar-nav.main-menu
                %li.active
                    %a{"href" => "#"} Home
                %li
                    %a{"href" => "#about"} About
                %li
                    %a{"href" => "#contact"} Contact
%div.container-fluid
    %div.row
        %div.school-create
            - if @school.errors.any?
                %ul
                    - @school.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                        %li
                            = msg
            %div#map-check
            %h2.header School Info
            = form_for @school do |f|
                = f.label :school_name, "School Name"
                = f.text_field :school_name, :class => 'form-control'
                = f.label :latitude, "Latitude"
                = f.text_field :latitude, :class => 'form-control', :id => "latitude"
                = f.label :longitude, "Longitude"
                = f.text_field :longitude, :class => 'form-control', :id => "longitude"
                = f.label :radius, "Radius"
                = f.text_field :radius, :class => 'form-control', :id => "radius"
                %div.admin-fields
                    %h2.header Admin Info
                    = f.fields_for :admins do |ff|
                        = ff.label :first_name
                        = ff.text_field :first_name, :class => 'form-control'
                        = ff.label :last_name
                        = ff.text_field :last_name, :class => 'form-control'
                        = ff.label :email
                        = ff.text_field :email, :class => 'form-control'
                        = ff.label :password
                        = ff.password_field :password, :class => 'form-control'
                        = ff.label :password_confirmation
                        = ff.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => 'form-control'
                        = ff.file_field :image
                = f.submit :class => 'submit-button btn btn-primary'
```

Comment: Have you added `accepts_nested_attributes_for :admin` to `School`?

Comment: yes the form saves fine but owner => true and status => "active" does not save

Comment: You have to pass the params though the form with hidden inputs. Build and new just create objects in memory which are gone as soon as Rails finishes sending the request.